# get JSON object data passed as function parameter in oracle 11g

Tags: json, oracle, object, oracle11g, parameters

welcome 
I need a library or any way to get JSON object passed as a parameter in function and manage it by oracle 11g
I Know this subject exists in oracle 12c and above but is there anyway doing this manner in oracle 11g 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no *support* for JSON in Oracle 11g, which means that you have (at least) three options:

- upgrade to 12c, if possible
- do everything *manually*
- install Apex (Oracle Application Express), at least version 5 (current is 20) as it offers [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635) API. You don't have to actually *use* Apex if you don't want, but - you could use its API for what you're planning to do

Answer (score 0):

Just install APEX in your database and you get access the APEX API which includes [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/APEX_JSON.html#GUID-11919ED6-CE3D-4497-8733-F56CD27B6BFF)

Then you can parse/create/extract data from json.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [it](https://github.com/pljson/pljson). Examples are also there in the repo.